# Añadir Título a mi Spinner

Tags: java, android

Cómo puedo poner un título a mi `spinner` y que no sea seleccionable?

Dejo el código de mi `spinner`

`clase`

```
   String[] zodiaco = {"Acuario (Ene. 20 - Feb. 18)", "Piscis (Feb. 19 - Marzo 20)", "Aries (Marzo 31 - Abril 19)", "Tauro (Abril 20 - Mayo 20)", "Géminis (Mayo 21 - Junio 20)", "Cáncer (Junio 21 - Julio 22)", "Leo (Julio 23 - Agosto 22)", "Virgo (Agosto 23 - Sep. 22)", "Libra (Sep. 23 - Oct. 22)", "Escorpio (Oct. 23 - Nov. 21)", "Sagitario (Nov. 22 - Dic. 21)", "Capricornio (Dic. 22 - Ene. 19)"};
    int flags[] = {R.drawable.icon_zod_acuario, R.drawable.icon_zod_piscis, R.drawable.icon_zod_aries, R.drawable.icon_zod_tauro, R.drawable.icon_zod_geminis, R.drawable.icon_zod_cancer, R.drawable.icon_zod_leo, R.drawable.icon_zod_virgo, R.drawable.icon_zod_libra, R.drawable.icon_zod_escorpio, R.drawable.icon_zod_sagitario, R.drawable.icon_zod_capricornio};

     Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerzodiaco);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), flags, zodiaco);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);


 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String description = zodiaco[position];
        editTextZodiaco.setText(description.split(" ")[0]);
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
```

`CustomAdapter`

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int flags[];
    String[] titulo_zodiaco;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] flags, String[] titulo_zodiaco) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.flags = flags;
        this.titulo_zodiaco = titulo_zodiaco;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return flags.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, null);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagenspinner);
        TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textspinner);
        icon.setImageResource(flags[i]);
        names.setText(titulo_zodiaco[i]);
        return view;
    }
}`
```

Como veréis en mi `clase` lo que selecciono en mi `spinner` se pasa en texto a mi `TextView` el título no quiero que se pueda enviar al `TextView`

Ya he probado con:

> spin.setPrompt("Title");

o en `xml`

> android:prompt="@string/titulo"

Pero no hace efecto

Comment: Hola ahora edito la pregunta pendiente, pero me llama la atención lo que deseas, quieres que ese titulo aparezca en el spinner y no este activo?

Comment: Vale! Gracias @Jorgesys ! Lo que quiero es que el `spinner` tenga un título, algo así como "Selecciona una opción" y al hacer click se despliegue mi `spinner` con sus opciones, pero que ese título no se envíe a mi `TextView` es decir, estar obligad@ a seleccionar una opción que no sea el título, espero que se me entienda bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es agregar un elemento al array, el cual servira de titulo:

> String[] zodiaco = {**"Selecciona una opción"**,"Acuario (Ene. 20 - Feb.
>   18)", "Piscis (Feb. 19 - Marzo 20)", "Aries (Marzo 31 - Abril 19)",
>   "Tauro (Abril 20 - Mayo 20)", "Géminis (Mayo 21 - Junio 20)", "Cáncer
>   (Junio 21 - Julio 22)", "Leo (Julio 23 - Agosto 22)", "Virgo (Agosto
>   23 - Sep. 22)", "Libra (Sep. 23 - Oct. 22)", "Escorpio (Oct. 23 - Nov.
>   21)", "Sagitario (Nov. 22 - Dic. 21)", "Capricornio (Dic. 22 - Ene.
>   19)"};

y validar al dar click en el primer elemento simplemente no realizar ninguna acción:

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       if(position !=0){ //Diferente del titulo.
           String description = zodiaco[position];
           editTextZodiaco.setText(description.split(" ")[0]);
       }
    }
```

Si deseas que siempre vaya al titulo después de realizar una acción lo puedes realizar mediante:

```
spinner.setSelection(0,true); //Indice 0, titulo.
```

---

> posición 1 si me deje seleccionarla pero no mande nada al EditText:

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       if(position == 1){ //Diferente del titulo.
           editTextZodiaco.setText("");
       }else if(position !=0){ //Diferente del titulo.
           String description = zodiaco[position];
           editTextZodiaco.setText(description.split(" ")[0]);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Simple y perfecto! Como siempre, gracias @Jorgesys, y si quisiera que la posición 1, no mandase nada al `EditTextZodiaco` podría hacer algo?

Comment: que bien!, bueno si tampoco el indice 1 deseas que realicé acción podrías validar:  if(position !=0 && position !=1){

Comment: No me has entendido, me refiero que la posición 1 si me deje seleccionarla pero no mande nada al `EditText` @Jorgesys

Comment: Gracias! Funciona perfecto, pero tuve que añadir un espacio, 
   if(position == 1){ 
       editTextZodiaco.setText(" "); para que no te diga que debes seleccionar una opción! @Jorgesys pásate por la pregunta que falta por terminar, si tienes tiempo, gracias !

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podrías hacer es crear un `SpinnerAdapter` y sobreescribir `View getDropDownView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`.

Si agregas tu titulo inicial como elemento 0, puedes en el `SpinnerAdapter` devolver una vista sin datos como:

```
class MiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Spinneradapter 

    @Override 
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if (position==0){
            // aquí armas la vista del elemento del titulo como quieras (vacio o con titulo pero sin elemento para seleccionar)
            return vistaTitulo;
        }
        //aquí devuelves los elementos regulares para el spinner
        return vistaElemento;
}
```

Y lo puedes combinar con la respuesta de @Jorgesys para filtrar la selección del titulo.